# Facebook messenger button it's not working using whatshelp.io?

Tags: jquery

I need to integrate conversion plugin in my application. And I have searching many plugin after I got [Whatshelp.io](https://whatshelp.io/) for the conversion. And using this I am go with widget and generate new script code and put in the body tag. But with this code in the Facebook messenger button is not working and WhatsApp button is working so any one know how can fix it please help me here below I have put it my script code:

This is my code:

```
 <!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var options = {
        facebook: "1629986620602076",// Facebook page ID
        whatsapp: "+123456789",
        company_logo_url: "//storage.whatshelp.io/widget/89/89b1/89b1c88a9066163bf664719188cc8a08/12115533_1629987150602023_6988602795927087362_n.png", // URL of company logo (png, jpg, gif)
        greeting_message: "Hello, how may we help you? Just send us a message now to get assistance.", // Text of greeting message
        call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
        position: "right", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        order: "facebook,whatsapp,email"
    };
    var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
    s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
})();
    </script>
    <!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full page Facebook page URL instead of the page ID?

Comment: @sideroxylon Yes I can put also full page facebook page url or also check with just page ID but still getting this issue?? can you please help me

Comment: In what way is it not working?  You're using the ID of the Whatshelp.io Facebook page.  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @sideroxylon I am going to click on messenger button don't react any type of after click on button. so i want to click on that button open there my facebook page for send message.

Comment: @sideroxylon yes I can used facebook page id also for the want script code.

Comment: Have you given whatshelp.io access to your Facebook page?  See [here](https://help.whatshelp.io/article/14-facebook-messenger)

Comment: @sideroxylon No I can't add. you mean I want to put in the setting my facebook page right?? after it's working right??

Comment: Yes, you need to give the widget access - otherwise it would be a security.  Check in your console when you click the button - you should get an error message from Facebook.

Comment: @sideroxylon No I can't get any type of the error in the console..

Comment: I think you need to use your page address, not ID, and, as set out in my comment the link above, you need to allow the widget to access your page.  WIthout both those, it won't work.